# Help me remember a 90s or 80s scfi parody like galaxy quest but not galaxy quest

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

So from what I remember it was on cable TV. The main hero was a TV actor zapped to a alien planet. It had a evil overlord with a virgin priestesses. She wants to get laid but he refuses because the next priestesses is only three. Regardless it's a parody things include a man who was maimed by the evil overlord wants revenge the hero eventually screws the virgin priestesses it cuts to scenes of a train going into a tunnel and a volcano erupting.

Answer (score 13):

This is [The Adventures of Captain Zoom in Outer Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Captain_Zoom_in_Outer_Space).

> A distant planet is in trouble. A young scientist picks up TV video
> signals from Earth and sees stage-managed heroic exploits of Captain
> Zoom on a children's TV show. He believes the heroics to be real. The
> young scientist snags the egotistical actor with some kind of space
> transport tractor beam, and beams the actor who was playing Captain
> Zoom to the besieged planet to aid its inhabitants.
>
> <sub><sup>[IMDB: Review](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112292/reviews)</sup></sub>

There's also a plot about a virgin priestess who'll lose her powers if she loses her virginity. As you can in the clip below, when they make love it's actually solar flares (and a comet) that we see, rather than a volcano, but the principle is very much the same.

Comment: Yes that's it thank you

Comment: @JackieRayGryderJr - Don't forget to upvote and click the "accepted" button on the left hand side of the answer :-)

Comment: @Valorum - Nice try ^^^. :p