# Campy SF mid 90s made-for-TV where a 'movie star' from our world saves another world

Tags: story-identification

Fragmented memories from my childhood:

- I thought the protagonist was Toby Huss (Artie from Adventures of Pete & Pete), but I cannot find anything that matches on his filmography.
- Protagonist definitely was 'dorky', he was an actor who played a superhero in our world and then was recruited by those from the other world who thought he was a real superhero.
- I also thought it was from one of the companies that made Hercules and Xena. It may have just been broadcast on the same channel.
- The whole thing is really campy but definitly had heart.
- Probably a "TV-14" rating.
- There is some type of reactor meltdown scene at the climax.
- Had a longer golden-age-of-sf title like "The Adventures of..."

Comment: [The Adventures of Captain Zoom in Outer Space](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145308/help-me-remember-a-90s-or-80s-scfi-parody-like-galaxy-quest-but-not-galaxy-quest/145309#145309)

Comment: The Adventures of Captain Zoom in Outer Space it is!!! :D